# How do I use Zookeeper as "Database" with Play Framework instead of traditional JDBC?

Tags: database, scala, model, playframework, apache-zookeeper

I am using Play framework 2.0.1 in scala to create an application that has basic stuff in the model but not very complicated. I would like the information in the model to be saved/requested/updated and deleted from a zookeeper instance.

How can i best go about this without crucially breaking play framework?

Comment: ZooKeeper isn't a database--it's a coordination server. From the docs: "ZooKeeper was not designed to be a general database or large object store. Instead, it manages coordination data." However, if you want to keep on using it, implement a custom service wrapper based on the [example code](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.3/javaExample.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer would be to tell you that ZooKeeper is not meant to be used as a general datastore/database; however, I am inclined to believe that you are really looking for something like MongoDB.

Check out [MongoDB Replica Sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) and [Election/Voting](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Voting). This should give you want you want. Much easier to manage than ZooKeeper and more useful for general application data storage needs.